# Test a non-idempotent method of a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, testing

I am searching for a clean and simple way to write tests for a single non-idempotent method of a webservice. So far, I couldn't find a satisfying way to handle this.

For example, I have a DELETE method, which deletes entities in a database. It returns a 200 in case of successful deletion of the given entity. In the test, I call it with a specific entity id which is then deleted. In case of a second test run, it will fail, because the entity doesn't exist anymore.

To workaround that, I would need to put e.g. a POST call within the test, to create an entity before deleting it. But that's mixing up my API tests. So, if I get a test failure, I can't be sure whether the POST method or the following DELETE failed. If possible, I only want one single endpoint to be called in one single test.

Is there a better way to come around that? Does there exist a standard pattern?

Comment: Using a database in a unit test seems weird.

Comment: It is OK to create entity via other API call. It is rarely possible to use only one API call in end-to-end tests

Comment: @talex ok, but that makes my tests much more interdependent and probably dependent from execution order. e.g. test1{PUT(1)}; test2{POST(1); DELETE(1)}. test2 will fail because entity 1 already exists. this will need a lot of more effort than independent tests...

Comment: You can use random id. It's very small chance to have collision

Comment: Or you can cleanup after test